# namespacing functions in a directory in R

Tags: r, namespaces

Let us say I have a directory with custom R functions.

i.e.,

```
myDir/f1.R
myDir/f2.R
```

How can I source them into R such that I keep the namespace?

i.e., to call them in R I'd call them like:

`myDir::f1(<input>)`

as opposed to `f1(<input>)`,

which is the default behavior when using source in the base package.

Comment: Is `sourceDir` really a base package? `library(sourceDir)`.... "there is no package called ‘sourceDir’" . I see a *function* called `sourceDir` in a somewhat obscure looking package called `xhmmScripts`. Is that the one?

Comment: @Hack-R I think they're just confused about terminology and are referring to the function created in the examples for the `source` function.

Comment: @Dason Oh, I see. Thanks. If you have that function readily available perhaps you can edit the question and stick it in?

Comment: sourceDir is a function in the base package ( i think ) if not just source is also ok, for the sake of this question it doesn't make much of a difference.

Comment: To call them with `myDir::f1(<input>)` you need to create a package called *myDir* and add your R files to the `/R` directory.

Answer (score 0):

This does not exactly answer your question but might help you anyway:
I often have a lot of functions to source / use in my everyday work and it got really annoying having so much function definitions in the global environment. My solution was to encapsulate related functions in a dummy function which returns a list:

```
myFunctionNameSpace <- function() {

    function1 <- function(x) {
        print(paste0("Function 1 was called with argument ", x))   
    }

    function2 <- function(x) {
        helperFunction1()
        print(paste0("Function 2 was called with argument ", x))
    }

    helperFunction1 <- function() {
        print("Helper function 1 was called.")
    }


    return(list(
        function1 = function1,
        function2 = function2
    ))
}

myFunctionNameSpace <- myFunctionNameSpace()
```

If you source the code above, you get a single object `myFunctionNameSpace` in your environment. You can then call the functions with the `$` operator:

```
myFunctionNameSpace$function1(17)
myFunctionNameSpace$function2(42)
```

Note that this also hides any "helper functions" which you do not want to export. It also would allow nesting of such "namespaces" and last but not least it works really well with RStudios auto-complete feature.

Comment: hi AEF, this makes sense, thanks for the suggestion.